# Why n in the compounded half-yearly replaced by 2n and not by $\frac n{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, actuarial-science

**Compound interest**

*Compounded Annually:*

Amount after one year = $P(1+\frac R{100})^n$

---

*Compounded half-yearly:*

Amount after half year = $P(1+\frac {R/2}{100})^{2n}$

---

Why **n** in the compounded half-yearly replaced by **2n** and not by $\frac n{2}$?

Comment: Because in some fixed number of years the number of half-yearly payments is twice the number of yearly payments?

Comment: After one year it should be $(\cdots)^1$ or $(\cdots)^2$. It is after $n$ years you get $(\cdots)^n$ and $(\cdots)^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent $n$ in the compound interest formula represents periods. The rate of interest must synchronize with the period. Generally, interest rate is given per annum (eg: 7% p.a). However, compounding period may be annual, half-yearly, quarterly, monthly, bi-weekly, daily or theoretically anything we want.

So, if the compounding is done half-yearly and rate of interest is given per annum, we need to normalize the rate of interest and the period in the exponent.

We do that by halving the rate of annual interest. This still leaves the exponent as annual periods. If compounding is done half-yearly, the periods goes up by a factor of 2. That is why we multiply the exponent by 2.

Here's a detailed worked example of Compound Interest:

[image: Worked example]

Comment: I didn't understand why that "n" is replaced with "2n". The reason that one year contains two half years doesn't convince me.

Comment: The meaning of compounding interest (as opposed to simple interest) is that the interest at the end of each period is reinvested and earns interest at the same rate. Think of it as n years = 2n half year periods. At the end of each half year period, you calculate the simple interest and add it to the principal and repeat this for 2n periods.

Comment: I've added an illustration. The formula is a shortcut to compute what is displayed as detailed working of the ending amount at the end of each period. Compounding means you have to calculate the reinvested amount at the end of the period which becomes the principal for the next period. Within each period it is a simple interest calculation (I = P * 1 * R).

Comment: Could you please improve your answer by deriving the general formula?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's compounded twice each year, not half a time each year. Thus each year contributes
$$
\left(1+\frac{R/2}{100}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{R/2}{100}\right)=
\left(1+\frac{R/2}{100}\right)^2
$$
to the total interest. Taken over $n$ years, this gives a total exponent of $2n$.

Comment: Nope, I didn't understand why that "n" is replaced with "2n".